# Syntax of Java Generics

Tags: java, android, generics, android-volley

I am new to using Java Generics and facing issues with its syntax. I tried solving this particular issue for long, reading many articles on internet and stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution. But I do believe there is solution to this problem-

So I have Generic Class as follows-

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {}
```

I am creating object of this class in this method:

```
 private <T> void makeGsonWebserviceRequest(int requestType, final String requestEndPoint,
          Object requestData, Type responseClass, Map<String, String> headers,
          final Handler successHandler, final Handler failureHandler) {

    final GsonRequest request;

    try {
        request = new GsonRequest<>(requestType, requestEndPoint, requestData, responseClass, headers,
                new Response.Listener<JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse response) {

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        addRequestToQueue(request);
    }
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
TypeToken<JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse<JsContact>> responseTypeToken = 
    new TypeToken<JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse<JsContact>>() {};

makeGsonWebserviceRequest(Request.Method.GET,
     context.getString(R.string.BASEURL) + context.getString(R.string.GETCONTACTLIST),
     null, responseTypeToken.getType(), createHeader(), successHandler, failureHandler);
```

So my Question is:

How to pass `<JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse<JsContact>>`, as Generic type, in `new GsonRequest<>` which lies in `makeGsonWebserviceRequest` method?

For reference, below is the model class:

```
public class JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("Version")
    protected String version;

    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    protected int statusCode;

    @SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
    protected String errorMessage;

    @SerializedName("Result")
    protected ArrayList<T> result;


    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ArrayList<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JaiSamadhiServiceBaseObjectResponse{" +
                "version='" + version + '\'' +
                ", statusCode=" + statusCode +
                ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
                ", result=" + result +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: `final GsonRequest request;` should already give you a warning about using the raw type. Why isn't This `GsonRequest<T>`?

Comment: "How to pass > as Generic type" What exactly is ">"?
What do you expect your generic type to be?

Comment: in the method you define : `final GsonRequest request;` - why not: `final GsonRequest<MyGenericType> request;`

Comment: @Mark: what should right in place of <MyGenericType> that I don't know

Comment: @Bifz: makeGsonWebserviceResponse is method which will be called at multiple places each type different class will be passed in Type responseClass

Comment: @dhke: I have given empty <> while construction class, hence warning is not being shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can pass the desired type as a method parameter:

```
private <T> void makeGsonWebserviceRequest(/*...*/ Class<T> requiredType)
```

Then you pass `JaiSamadhiServiceBaseListResponse.class` as argument.

Comment: bro you are awesome!!